# Where to put the language for an AC_DEFUN?

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf

I'm using an alternate [`AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47160617/608639) as shown below.

```
BAD_RESULT="fatal|error|unknown|unrecognized|illegal|ignored|not found|not exist|cannot find"

AC_DEFUN([XXX_COMPILE_IFELSE],
   [AC_REQUIRE([AC_PROG_EGREP])
   AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(
      [$1],
      [retval=0
        if $EGREP -i -c -E "$BAD_RESULT" conftest.err >/dev/null; then retval=1; fi
      ],[retval=1]
   )
   AS_IF([test $retval = 0],[$2],[$3])]
)
```

When I `autoreconf` to create the `configure` scipt, the alternate is generating a lot of warnings like:

```
configure.ac:812: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:194: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2591: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2607: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
configure.ac:152: XXX_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
configure.ac:812: the top level
```

The Autotools documents ([here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/autoconf-2.57/html_chapter/autoconf_6.html) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Macro-Definitions.html) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Running-the-Compiler.html)) don't discuss where to put the language. I tried to bookend `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` with calls to `AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])` and `AC_LANG_POP` but it did not squash the warning.

Where do I tell machinery that the language is C++?

---

Here is an example of using `XXX_COMPILE_IFELSE`.

```
XXX_PROGRAM="#include <wmmintrin.h>
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     __m128i x;
     x=_mm_aesenc_si128(x,x);
     x=_mm_aesenclast_si128(x,x);
     return 0;
  }"

CXXFLAGS="-xarch=aes"
AC_MSG_CHECKING([if $CXXNAME supports $CXXFLAGS])
XXX_COMPILE_IFELSE(
  [$XXX_PROGRAM],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes]); AC_SUBST([tr_RESULT], [1])],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT([no]);  AC_SUBST([tr_RESULT], [0])]
)
```

---

The head of `configure.ac` has the following. It seems like it is not being honored since switching to `XXX_COMPILE_IFELSE`.

```
AC_INIT([Crypto++], [7.1], ...)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([local.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile] [libcryptopp.pc])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([configure.ac])

AM_PROG_AS
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
LT_INIT

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_PROG_GREP

## Assert this once to avoid surprises
AC_LANG_ASSERT([C++])
```

Comment: You seem to be misreading the error message.  It complains about missing [`AC_LANG_SOURCE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/autoconf.html#index-AC_005fLANG_005fSOURCE-954), which is a macro for generating / massaging program source code, not for specifying which language such code is written in.

Comment: I think it wants you to use `AC_LANG_SOURCE()` to condition the source code presented as the first argument to `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`.  Doing so is not documented as a requirement, but then again, Autoconf is emitting a warning, not an error.  It could be safe to ignore this warning for your particular purposes, but do read up on what `AC_LANG_SOURCE` would actually do for you if you used it.